# Django - Storing a list of all sorted posts

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to build a Reddit or Hackernews-style community section for my website. Upvotes and downvotes are already implemented as well as date and time posted. The Post model has a method that returns a score for a particular post calculated based on upvotes, downvotes, and time posted. So far so good.

Now I don't want to have to sort all my posts every single time a user loads a page. I think the solution to this (please correct me if I'm wrong) is to run a script every few minutes that sorts all the posts by score and saves them. Then when a user tries to load the front page the view will return the first 20 posts in the list of sorted posts, if someone loads the second page the view will return the next 20 items in the list and so on.

My naive approach was to have a model that looked something like this:

```
class SortedPosts(models.Model):
    sortedPosts = models.ListField
```

And then a script to run every minute that looked like this:

```
from myproject.models import Post, SortedPosts
posts = Post.objects.all()
SortedPosts.sortedPosts = sorted(posts, key = lambda Post: Post.getScore())
SortedPosts.sortedPosts.save()
```

But alas, there is no such thing as a ListField (at least in vanilla Django.) When I search on SO, the only solution I've found is to serialize the list and store it in a TextField. That feels wrong. Is it?

The fact that there is no ListField in Django makes me suspect that the way I've set out to do this is incorrect in a more fundamental way. What would the correct way to do this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in your particular situation the serialization/deserialization procedure
you imagine, might take even more time than sorting the posts with each request.

1000 objects are ridiculesly few , for a postgresql/mysql database.

Do nothing. If the need arises, use [redis](http://redis.io/).

Either you need a caching mechanism or you don't. In your case seems overkill.

UPDATE:

```
Good to know! What if my Post model has a rank field that is kept updated. Can I index by that field and somehow retrieve my posts in order?
```

all django fields take the optional parameter "db_index". If you set it to `True` it will
build an index on it.

Then I suppose you want to do something like `Post.objects.order_by('-rank')`

The "-" signifies `descending` order. Remove it and you have `ascending` order.

Comment: Good to know! What if my Post model has a rank field that is kept updated. Can I index by that field and somehow retrieve my posts in order? Something like Post.objects.indexedBy('rank') or something equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you have decided that the database (whatever you are using) is just too dang slow, and that Python is also just way too slow to be sorting your list for you on each request, then the next 'proper' way to really go about this is with a caching strategy using any of the numerous third party tools available.

Look at [memcached](http://memcached.org/).

Comment: That may happen one day, and I'm sure there will be a slew of optimizations to be done on that front, but I haven't quite gotten there yet. Let's say that I only have 100 posts and only anticipate growing to 1000 over the next 6 months. Sorting and storing won't be so bad. Right now I'm looking for a way to do this at all in Django that isn't what feels like a hack (serializing and storing in a text field.)

Comment: Sorting 1,000 posts using either your database, or directly in Python is going to have such a miniscule impact on processing/load time that it is a non-issue. I think you might be trying to fix something that is not broken.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't phrasing my question correctly: I'm not asking about the fastest way to sort through a list and store it. I don't know how to store a list in Django period. That's the issue. I know I can serialize my list and store it in a textfield and then decode it, which will probably be fine with only 1000 posts, but it feels like a hack and the wrong way to do it, so I'm asking what the proper way to store a list of posts in Django is.